# Get ADInterstitialAd with more than 20,000 request, but none displayed

Tags: iphone, iad

I have an app update with iAd.

I use "ADInterstitialAd" to display a full screen ad.

when I'm testing the app with Xcode, The app show a test iAd,as I'm want.

but when upload to app store, It have send over 20,000 request, but none display.

my program is flow the Apple's demo "iAdInterstitialSuite / ADGame"

is there any thing wrong I made??

prethanks guys' help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Apple just doesn't have an ad to show. I'm not sure how they make the decisions on when they'll actually show the ad or not. With 200,000 requests seems like you should see it sometimes. Perhaps you're asking for an ad too often and they're throttling you?

Make sure you handle the ad error states correctly. That will tell you why it's happening.